# Taking student scores from a file, calculating averages, and printing

Tags: java, beginner

This program takes scores for each student from a .txt file and calculates their averages, as well as the average for each assignment and the class overall. This program works properly, just curious if I can make it look more professional.

Scores.txt

```
5
6
95.2 89.1 98.0 78.9 100 67
100 99.6 100 100 90.1 82.2
100 85.5 85.1 74 81 79.4
98.6 71.5 68.9 62.4 56.9 0
100 100 100 88.3 91.6 81.3
```

StudentGradeBookScores.java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
public class StudentGradebookScores {
  public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {


    File inputFile = new File("scores.txt");
    Scanner data = new Scanner(inputFile);
    DecimalFormat averages = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    int students = data.nextInt();
    int assignments = data.nextInt();
    double gradebook[][] = new double [students + 1][assignments + 1];

    //putting the scores into the array
    for (int i=0; i<students; i++) { //rows
      for (int j=0; j<assignments; j++) { //coloums
        gradebook[i][j] = data.nextDouble();
      }
    }

    //calculating the average assignment score for each student (coloums)
    for (int i=0; i<students; i++) {
      double studentTotal = 0;
      for (int j=0; j<assignments; j++) {
        studentTotal = studentTotal + gradebook[i][j];
      }
      gradebook[i][assignments] = studentTotal/assignments;
    }

    //calculating the average score of each assigment for all students (rows)
    for (int j=0; j<assignments; j++) {
      double assignmentTotal = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<students; i++) {
        assignmentTotal = assignmentTotal + gradebook[i][j];
      }
      gradebook[students][j] = assignmentTotal/students;
    }


    //printing the gradebook
    System.out.print("\t\t\t\tAssignment #:\n\t\t");
    for (int j=0; j<assignments; j++) {
      System.out.print((j+1) + "\t"); 
    }

    System.out.println("Avg");
    for (int i=0; i<students; i++) {
      System.out.print("Student #" + (i+1) + ":\t");
      for (int j=0; j<assignments; j++) {
        System.out.print(gradebook[i][j] + "\t");
      }
      System.out.println(averages.format(gradebook[i][assignments]));
    }
    System.out.print("Average\t\t");
    for (int j=0; j<assignments; j++) {
      System.out.print(averages.format(gradebook[students][j]) + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();

    double overallAvg = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<students; i++) {
      overallAvg = overallAvg + gradebook[i][assignments];
    }

    System.out.println("\nOverall Average: " + averages.format(overallAvg/students));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you use Java 8, or is this strictly < Java 8?

Comment: Yes I can use Java 8! I would prefer to use the modern methods

Answer (score 8):

Declaring that `main() throws IOException` is probably the right thing to do for a simple program like this.  A lot of beginners try to catch an exception that they don't have any idea how to handle properly.

That's a lot of code to be stuffed into a single `main()` function.  Ideally, you should develop classes such that `main()` contains just a minimal amount of code, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (Scanner input = args.length > 0 ? new Scanner(new File(args[0])) :
                                           new Scanner(System.in)) {
        GradeBook book = new GradeBook(input);
        System.out.println(book);
        System.out.printf("Overall Average: %s\n", 
                          FMT.format(book.average()));
    }
}
```

Hard-coding an input filename makes it hard to reuse your code.  I've modified it to read from either a filename specified on the command line or from `System.in`.

You should be able to avoid having to explicitly specify the dimensions of the data in the file.

Using Java 8 streams removes a lot of tedious looping from the implementation.  Here is the rest of my suggested implementation:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class GradeBook {
    private List<double[]> students;
    private static final DecimalFormat FMT = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

    public GradeBook(Scanner input) {
        this.students = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            double[] student = Arrays.stream(input.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+"))
                  .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                  .toArray();
            students.add(student);
        }
    }

    public double getScore(int student, int assignment) {
        return this.students.get(student)[assignment];
    }

    public double averageForStudent(int student) {
        return Arrays.stream(this.students.get(student))
                     .average()
                     .getAsDouble();
    }

    public double averageForAssignment(int assignment) {
        return this.students.stream()
                   .mapToDouble((assignments) -> assignments[assignment])
                   .average()
                   .getAsDouble();
    }

    public double average() {
        return IntStream.range(0, this.students.size())
                        .mapToDouble((s) -> this.averageForStudent(s))
                        .average()
                        .getAsDouble();
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        int numAssignments = this.students.stream()
                                 .mapToInt((assignments) -> assignments.length)
                                 .max()
                                 .getAsInt();

        // Header
        out.append("\t\t\t\tAssignment #:\n\t\t");
        for (int a = 0; a < numAssignments; a++) {
           out.append(a + 1).append('\t'); 
        }
        out.append("Avg\n");

        // Body
        for (int s = 0; s < this.students.size(); s++) {
            out.append("Student #").append(s + 1).append(":\t");
            for (int a = 0; a < numAssignments; a++) {
                out.append(FMT.format(this.getScore(s, a))).append('\t');
            }
            out.append(FMT.format(this.averageForStudent(s))).append('\n');
        }

        // Footer
        out.append("Average\t\t");
        for (int a = 0; a < numAssignments; a++) {
            out.append(FMT.format(this.averageForAssignment(a))).append('\t');
        }
        out.append('\n');

        return out.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner input = args.length > 0 ? new Scanner(new File(args[0])) :
                                               new Scanner(System.in)) {
            GradeBook book = new GradeBook(input);
            System.out.println(book);
            System.out.printf("Overall Average: %s\n",
                              FMT.format(book.average()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> //putting the scores into the array
> for (int i=0; i<students; i++) { //rows
>   for (int j=0; j<assignments; j++) { //coloums
>     gradebook[i][j] = data.nextDouble();
>   }
> }
> ```

Comments should describe **why** something is done. The code itself should describe **what** is done by using descriptive names vor variables etc.

Usually one would use `i` and `j` as looping variables, but if you feel that you need to add the comments `//rows` and `//coloums` where the later is spelled wrong too, you should consider to just name the looping variables right.

Giving the variables some space to breathe will also add readability to your code.

The default indentation level for java code is 4 spaces.

```
for (int row = 0; row < students; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < assignments; column++) {
        gradebook[row][column] = data.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another take on (ab?)using the power of Java 8 streams...

@200_success's solution treats each line as a `double[]` array of scores, which works well enough. Taking the idea one step further, we can write our own `Collector` to directly map each score into a `Result` object, with references to a student and assignment.

```
public final class Result {
    private final int student;
    private final int assignment;
    private final double score;

    public Result(int student, int assignment, double score) {
        this.student = student;
        this.assignment = assignment;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public int getAssignment() {
        return assignment;
    }

    public double getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}
```

I suppose the `Result` class is straight-forward...

```
public final class ScoreCollector implements
        Collector<String, Collection<Result>, Collection<Result>> {

    private int numStudents = -1;
    private int numAssignments = -1;
    private int currentStudent = 0;

    @Override
    public Supplier<Collection<Result>> supplier() {
        return ArrayList::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Collection<Result>, String> accumulator() {
        return (collection, line) -> {
            if (isRecord(line)) {
                collection.addAll(toResults(line));
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Collection<Result>> combiner() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Collection<Result>, Collection<Result>> finisher() {
        return accumulator -> accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return EnumSet.noneOf(Characteristics.class);
    }

    private boolean isRecord(final String line) {
        if (numStudents == -1) {
            numStudents = Integer.parseInt(line);
            return false;
        } else if (numAssignments == -1) {
            numAssignments = Integer.parseInt(line);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private Collection<Result> toResults(final String line) {
        final int student = ++currentStudent;
        final int[] assignment = new int[1];
        return Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s", numAssignments))
                .map(v -> new Result(student, ++assignment[0], Double.parseDouble(v)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Our custom `ScoreCollector` has to perform a few things:

1. Parse and effectively ignore the first (number of students) and second (number of assignment) lines, optionally validating the later steps against these two values.
2. Convert a line into a `Collection<Result>` while being aware of the current student (i.e. line) and assignment.
3. Accumulate the resulting `Collection<Result>` into a final `Collection<Result>`.
4. Returning the final `Collection<Result>`.

The `accumulator()` method performs the first two steps, through `isRecord()` validation and then converting with `toResults()`. Setting instance variables in `isRecord()` does seem a bit odd, I'm actually open to comments on this...

Referencing of the current student and assignment is squarely done in `toResults()`, by incrementing on a `currentStudent` variable and a temporary one-element `assignment` array. In the code above, `line.split()` is called with the second argument `numAssignments`, which is the total number of expected scores per student. This will expectedly throw an `Exception` if we have mismatched number of scores. *You can omit this argument for flexibility.*

Things get easier after coding `ScoreCollector`. The benefits of dealing with just a single `Collection<Result>` is that you can apply more streaming functions on it based on the values encapsulated in each `Result` object. For illustration, I went with an alternative output of showing the maximum and minimum scores per student and per assignment. The only calculation I did not derive is the "overall average", as I'm not too sure how that will be interpreted. Anyways, code please:

```
private static final String FORMAT = "%s #%d\tAverage: %.2f\tMax: %.2f\tMin: %.2f%n";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(
            "scores.txt").toURI()))) {
        final Collection<Result> result = lines.collect(new ScoreCollector());
        groupAndPrint(result, Result::getStudent, "Student");
        groupAndPrint(result, Result::getAssignment, "Assignment");
    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("boxing")
private static void groupAndPrint(final Collection<Result> collection,
        final Function<Result, ?> classifier, final String label) {
    collection
            .stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(classifier,
                            Collectors.summarizingDouble(Result::getScore)))
            .forEach(
                    (key, summary) -> {
                        System.out.printf(FORMAT, label, key, summary.getAverage(),
                                summary.getMax(), summary.getMin());
                    });
}
```

I am using `try-catch` on opening the file using Java 8's new `Files.lines()` method, and from that `Stream` of `lines`, we collect using our `ScoreCollector`. We then use a helper method `groupAndPrint` to *group by* our `Collection<Result>` with the desired classifer, which will be either student (`Result::getStudent`) or assignment (`Result::getAssignment`) in our case. Afterwards, it's just a quick call to `Collectors.summarizingDouble()` on our scores, and we can easily print out the average, maximum and minimum scores per student/assignment.

```
Student #1      Average: 88.03      Max: 100.00     Min: 67.00
Student #2      Average: 95.32      Max: 100.00     Min: 82.20
Student #3      Average: 84.17      Max: 100.00     Min: 74.00
Student #4      Average: 59.72      Max: 98.60      Min: 0.00
Student #5      Average: 93.53      Max: 100.00     Min: 81.30
Assignment #1   Average: 98.76      Max: 100.00     Min: 95.20
Assignment #2   Average: 89.14      Max: 100.00     Min: 71.50
Assignment #3   Average: 90.40      Max: 100.00     Min: 68.90
Assignment #4   Average: 80.72      Max: 100.00     Min: 62.40
Assignment #5   Average: 83.92      Max: 100.00     Min: 56.90
Assignment #6   Average: 61.98      Max: 82.20      Min: 0.00
```

I hope my usage of Java 8 streams is still a somewhat sane solution to your question, with more flexibility for alternative outputs...